# assistance needed for error when embedding youtube video

Tags: html, css, iframe, youtube, embed

All I'm trying to do is embed one youtube video onto my web page using the iframe tag :

```
<iframe width = "250" height = "150" src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/watch?v=GieJ52nBkGg"></iframe>
```

Whenever I hit play I get an error message saying please try again later, and I'm given a playback id. I've tried searching for answers since this is a common issue but haven't had any luck. What should I change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see you have a malformed embed url in the code. YouTube embed codes don't contain the `watch?` option. Try changing the code from

`https://www.youtube.com/embed/watch?v=GieJ52nBkGg` to `https://www.youtube.com/embed/GieJ52nBkGg`

This should fix your issue

Answer (score 0):

Try

`<iframe width="250" height="150" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/GieJ52nBkGg"></iframe>`

Youtube's iframe embed is not compatible with the format of URL you used.